# Getting g++ to work on Mac with Xcode

Tags: osx, g++

In trying to get g++ to work in terminal I ran a command which I have now learned is outdated.

I think this is why running g++ in terminal returns an error but I am unsure.

If I try to run any .cpp in terminal I get the error message:

```
xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)
```

I have xcode installed and have installed command line tools. However after doing so, I ran the command below:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/
```

What have I done, and what should I do?

Comment: Wait, you're trying to *run* a `.cpp` (C++ source code) file, as opposed to compile it? What happens if you just do `g++ -o program program.cpp` ?

Comment: What command did you type that gave the `xcrun` error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have simply pointed `xcode-select` at the wrong part of the Xcode directory structure.  You should be able to undo this with:

```
xcode-select -reset
```

In the future, if you need it, The `xcode-select` tool can find what it needs by being given just the path to the Xcode app you want to use:

```
xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```